# How do I implement EE security best practice with vhost dedicated server

Tags: security

I was attempting the implement the additional security steps highlighted in the post installation documentation [here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/best_practices.html) on a dedicated server.  I came to realize after talking with a Rackspace, my hosting provider, that this document and setup is intended for shared hosting as my vhosted dedicated server is not laid out in the manner described in the tutorial.

Anyone ever accomplished this? Google searches keep turning up dedicated hosting solutions. Rackspace offered a solution of creating an additional folder inside my current folder housing everything and than redirect to this nested folder allowing me to place admin files at the same level, they were not aware of how this would affect EE though.

Comment: You should be able to rename the system directory and admin.php file, so those steps are ok. Do you have ftp access to the web root only (may be named httpdocs), or can you go up one level?

Comment: Which Rackspace plan are you on? I have a Rackspace cloud virtual server and do this on every project now. If you can set up vhosts, you should be able to access each vhost at the folder level above httpdocs or public.

Comment: This might help? You can set up symlinks which EE will see as regular directories. That may have been what Rackspace (and Mark) were talking about. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654600/git-deploying-to-environments-with-different-web-root-directory-names/14655219#14655219

Comment: @MarkJ.Reeves We are on Rackspace Managed Cloud Servers. We have vhosts set up.  My folder structure looks like this: -/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com

If this what you expect? could I just put the admin files in "www"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We are on Rackspace Managed Cloud Servers. We have vhosts set up. My folder structure looks like this: -/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com If this what you expect? could I just put the admin files in "www"?

My setup is the same. I configure my vhosts with the following:

```
mysite.com
  database
  log
  public
  system
```

- Public is where the vhost actually points to to serve up the website.
- Log is where log files are stored.
- Database is a folder I create to store mysql dump files to move copies of my db around.
- System is the EE system directory, one level up from `index.php`.

Once you change your `index.php` and `admin.php` to use `../` syntax to look 1 directory up, it should all work.

We also use [Focus Lab's Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) approach.

Within public, I create a `ee` directory that contains `config` and `third_party`. This is where I manage third party add-ons and my config.php within the `public` directory.

I also store `templates` in the public directory, nested within another directory containing our front-end assets (images, css, js). This lets us point CodeKit at 1 directory instead of having it monitor the whole application.

If you're accessing the server via SSH/command line, your vhost configurations are typically in a location such as `/etc/apache2/sites-available` (on Ubuntu). If you edit that file, you'll see that you can point the website to the public directory. I'm assuming this is what they're referring to when they say "redirect to this nested folder."

A few years back I printed out a set of Slicehost's articles and put them in a binder. I use those every time I set up a new Ubuntu server, from SSH accounts to firewall to Apache/PHP/MySQL and vhost config. You can [start here](http://articles.slicehost.com/ubuntu-10) or jump right to [vhosts config](http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/5/19/apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-part-1).

Comment: Reeves suggestion is accurate. Basically, besides changing the system folder's name and the admin.php file name, you can move the `/system/` folder above the `public` folder so its not accessible via the web. So if `public` is the folder your domain name is pointed at, you just have to move the folder a level up.

Comment: Mark - This is exactly what I am trying to accomplish, including implementation of focus labs master config. I will use this as a guide. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Updated with a few more helpful links. Good luck!